# Can a 2014 15" MBP simultaneously run both 4k and QHD external monitors?

Tags: display, 4k

I have a 15" mid-2014 MBP (NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB).   It is currently running two external monitors, a 4k and an HD (1920 x 1080),  both at 60 Hz refresh.

I'd like to know if it can instead run 4k + QHD (2560x1440 or 2560x1600), also at 60 Hz refresh.

There have been other questions about running multiple monitors with a mid-2014 MBP:

[mid-2014 rMBP multiple monitors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189027/mid-2014-rmbp-multiple-monitors)

[Running 3 External Monitors off a Mid 2014 MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260003/running-3-external-monitors-off-a-mid-2014-macbook-pro)

But none specifically addresses the question of whether it can do 4k + QHD.

Also, if it can run the QHD, can I connect it via HDMI, or would I need TB?

I'd prefer to hear from someone who is (or has tried to) actually run both a 4k and QHD on a 15" mid-2014 MBP w/ the above-listed graphics card.

### UPDATE, 4/1/20:

I now have the MPB driving three external monitors:  4k, WUXGA (1920 x 1200) and HD (1920 x 1080).  Given  this, I expect it would have no problem driving 1 x 4k and 1 x QHD, since 1 x WUXGA + 1 x HD has more pixels than 1 x QHD (I'm assuming equal color depths, as is the case here):

[(1920 x 1200) + (1920 x 1080)]/(2560x1600) = 1.06875, and

[(1920 x 1200) + (1920 x 1080)]/(2560x1440) = 1.1875

Here's a screenshot from the Graphics/Displays section of the System Information report:

[image]

Comment: The connection itself isn’t the issue, but it wouldn’t be TB unless you have a TB port **and** a TB monitor.  For good reliability, go with DisplayPort.  It’s what natively output from the MBP and if you get a monitor with a DP input, there’s no conversion like there would be with HDMI.

Comment: @Allan.  TB->DP is how my 4k monitor is connected.  The HD monitor is currently connected via HDMI, and seems to work fine (though I've not tried TB->DP to see if the pic improves; I should do this).  But it sounds like you're saying that, if I can run a QHD in place of the HD, I should (as with my 4k) also connect it using TB->DP.  Currently, both my TB ports are used, one for the 4k, the other for ethernet.  If I need to connect the QHD via TB, what would be the best configuration to accomplish this?  Split the 2nd TB port into ethernet and QHD?  See if I can do ethernet via HDMI?

Comment: Yes.  If you can go with DisplayPort, go that way.  To the second monitor, Ethernet and whatever else you’d like/need I would go with a dock like what I recommended in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384444/119271). I like DisplayPort better because you should have better control over your monitors and should have zero issues getting a 4K and QHD to work.

Comment: @Allan Thanks.  Might also get better results, with the DP connection, if I decide to calibrate it with my X-Rite i1. But how can you be sure my graphics card could drive both without having tested it? ["should have zero issues getting a 4K and QHD to work."] It is certain I can't drive two 4k's, right? (which is too bad, since this one, for $230, seems serviceable as a 2nd monitor:  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07LBM2DCC/ref=psdc_1292115011_t2_B073VYVX5S?th=1). OTOH the dock in your answer doesn't seem practical for me; it costs as much as the 2nd monitor, and is USB-C (not avail. on 2014 MBP).

Comment: I’m just confident in that particular model - it’s got the discrete GPU so it’s got the horsepower to drive the two external monitors at 2560x1600.  See:  https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.8-15-iris-only-mid-2014-retina-display-specs.html.  I can’t speak to that monitor per se (I stick to Dell Ultrasharp line), but even though it’s 4K it should downscale to QHD.  Plus you’ll be 4K ready when you get your next machine.

Comment: @Allan I think you might misunderstand what I want. I've currently got a 4k Dell as my primary monitor, really enjoy its sharpness, and *don't* want the graphics card to be forced to downscale it because I've connected a 2nd monitor.  I.e., I want to know the highest-res 2nd monitor I can connect *without* downscaling.  [I.e. I don't want to end up with 2 x (2560 x 1600).]

Comment: You might be right - now that you phrased it that way.  I was hearing it in my head differently.  Though the *hardware* will support it, it’s whether macOS will be a PITA or not.

Comment: @Allan  I think it's the other way around.  We know MacOS has no problems supporting 2 x 4k.  Indeed, if the hardware is up to it, MacOS has no problems running *twelve* 4k displays at full resolution and 60 Hz (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210228).  Rather, the question is whether my hardware will support 2 x 4k (or even 4k + QDH), at full resolution and 60 Hz.  If my hardware can support it, MacOS will be fine.  So the limitation isn't the software, it's the hardware.